# In what circumstances do i need my own initializes to initialize object?

Tags: objective-c

I know objective c has built in 'init' method to initialize object. But  i want to know In what circumstances do i need my own initializes to initialize object?
I want to know what value is assigned to self when  i  invoke  'self = [super init]'

Comment: Please try to be more elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You only need your own initializer when you need your object to default to a state that is different than what the compiler will enforce.  That is, all instance variables are initialized to 0 (for integer-like types) or 0.0 (for floating point types).  That means all pointers are nil and all numbers are 0(.0).  If you need to initialize anything to a different value (creating internal container objects, for example), you need your own initializer.

Similarly, if your class inherits from a class that implements its own initializer, you only need your own if you want your state to be different than the superclass's.